# Print a CSV file from SAS using libname

Tags: csv, sas, proc, proc-sql

I am trying to export data from SAS into a CSV file from a table I created using `PROC SQL`. (test_data was created using a `PROC SQL Select` statement)
I tried the following code:

```
LIBNAME libout "C:\Users\Outbox";
proc export data=test_data dbms=csv replace outfile="&libout.\test_data.csv";
run;
```

When running this code snipped the following error shows up:

```
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, C:\windows\system32\&libout.\test_data.csv.
```

I know I can specify the path using a string for `outfile` directly, but I am trying to use a `LIBNAME` for later application in another system instead. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libname` is for SAS dataset; `filename` is for files.

```
filename fileout "C:\Users\Outbox\test_data.csv";
proc export data=test_data dbms=csv replace outfile=fileout;
run;
```

You could also use a macro variable if you want to just specify the directory, similar to Superfluous's answer.  But don't put quotes around it there.

```
%let outdir = c:\users\outbox;
proc export data=test_data dbms=csv replace outfile="&outdir.\test_data.csv";
run;
```

In either case you can specify the filename or the macro variable in one location and then use it in a very different location, they don't have to be sequential - just like libnames.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would use a libname if you wanted to store a SAS dataset. In this case, you want to save a csv file, so you just need a macro: `%let libout = "C:\Users\Outbox";`